# Swift: How to programmatically move the alignment of only the textLabel in Table View

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem with my Table View alignment.

Each time the disclosure indicator appears, my 'centered' text is moved off center to the left due to the reduced size of the content view frame.

I have used the following code to manually adjust that :

```
let cellMargin = ((cell.frame.size.width - cell.contentView.frame.size.width) / 2)
self.leftMargin.constant = cellMargin
```

This works, but the problem is that the separator line between each cell is also inset by the same left margin, which is aesthetically even worse than an off-center textLabel.

Can anybody help me resolve the situation? All I need is the textLabel to be centered in the cell regardless of the presence of a disclosure indicator.

Thanks all!

Comment: You can just set the textLabel.textAlignment = .Center.

Comment: Thanks for the response but unfortunately that doesn't work. I'm already using that code but because the content view is reduced in size due the the presence of the disclosure indicator, 'center' is actually not in the center of the cell...